# Laravel Passport: How to validate client IP when requesting API

Tags: laravel, ip-address, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

I'm using Laravel Passport as my API authentication mechanism. Everything is working as expected, but i need to add an extra validation for each request. 
The idea is to validate the client IP Address alongside the access_token that is sent to the server.

Any idea how i can accomplish this?

**UPDATE:** I want to check if the IP used in the authentication (when the user logged in) is the same as the one doing the requestes. If the IP is different, the client must login again.

Comment: validate IP format or validate IP per session? I suspect the latter, however think about wat that means for users that toggle wifi / 4g on their mobile phone :)

Comment: Validate the IP per session. I actually thought of that :) Every time the IP changes for that token, the user must login again :)

Comment: idea: add one field to User's table (last_login_ip), when attempt login success then clean old sessions of user and update ip value

Comment: @raksaeng how/where can i override the passport auth method in order to check the ip when validating the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ip address could be checked any where, but if require to get before Passport need middleware:

create **app/Http/Middleware/IpMiddleware.php** class

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class IpMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, \Closure $next)
    {
        $ip = null;
        if (getenv('HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP')) {
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP');
        } else if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')) {
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        } else if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        } else if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')) {
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        } else if (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        } else if (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')) {
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        } else if (getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')) {
            $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        }
        if (!$ip || $ip === '::1') {
            $ip = $request->ip();
        }
        $ipAddress = \explode(',', $ip ?? '127.0.0.1')[0];
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

in **app/Http/Kernel.php** add         **'ip' => \App\Http\Middleware\IpMiddleware::class,**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'ip' => \App\Http\Middleware\IpMiddleware::class,
];
```

in `routes/web.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['ip', 'auth:api']], function () {
    //your routes
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a middleware, and in that middleware add a new variable to session info:

```
public function handle(Request $request)
{
  $request->session()->set('initial_ip', $request->ip());

  return $next(...);
}
```

after that, you can just fetch this value from session anywhere in the code, and compare it with the current $request->ip() value.

Comment: thanks for the help. I ended up choosing @raksaeng's solution as the correct answer because it was more detailed.