# How to store user's IP alongside his access token and then compare it to his current IP when verifying his token in laravel API?

Tags: php, laravel, api, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

So... I have a front-end application, which sends requests to an API, that I'm writing in laravel.

This is the over-simplified laravel way, to create access tokens

```
$user = Auth::user();
$token = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
```

But when creating this token, I want to somehow store user's IP to the same DB record, that laravel will store the newly created access token (which is located in this SQL table `oauth_access_tokens`).

When the user requests some "sensitive" data, then the server should compare the IP address that the user is currently sending those requests from to the one, that his access token was created with.

Is it possible without somehow updating the DB record after creating the access token or without creating a new table, that I'm gonnna store those IP's into or do I have to program the whole access token thing by myself and implement that IP verification by myself too?

P.S. this question doesn't help me at all -> [Laravel Passport: How to validate client IP when requesting API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632114/laravel-passport-how-to-validate-client-ip-when-requesting-api)

Comment: I'd advise against this. There are many legitimate reasons why consecutive requests from the same user may originate from a different IP address.

Comment: @rjdown Well yeah, but on the other hand, it's more secure and if the user wants to "request" from another IP address, then he can just login again and create new access token

Comment: Logging in again won't help in this case, because their next request may change the IP again. And again. And again. This can affect mobile users, people using some VPNs and proxies, and some network setups using multiple connections. It may also cause problems if you put your service behind some form of load balancing or CDN. Of course, it's up to you if you want to handle all the support requests for these issues :D

Answer (score 1):

**VALIDATING VIA IP ADDRESS**

Have to say I agree with rjdown's points and would not do this myself. There are standard solutions for IP whitelisting.

There is an interesting software pattern you could use though.

**BUILD CLAIMS WHEN AN ACCESS TOKEN IS FIRST RECEIVED**

Treat the IP address as a kind of claim, then include it in the API's claims object. Of course, it is not a highly secured / digitally verifiable claim such as the token's user id. Then cache claims in memory.

**IMPLEMENT AN IP ADDRESS FILTER**

On each subsequent API request, quickly lookup claims. Then run a filter class to compare the IP of the original to the current request.

**MORE ON THIS DESIGN PATTERN**

- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/)
- [Sample Code - see the Authorizer class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/tree/master/api/src/host/oauth)

Answer (score 0):

Each authenticated user has a session, so you can save IP to session and check it later.

For example get current IP:

```php
$currentIp = Request::ip();
```

Later you can get IP of another request and compare it to the last saved.

[Sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session):

```php
$old_ip = session('ip', null);
$current_ip = Request::ip();
if ($old_ip == null) {
  session(['ip' => $current_ip]);
} else if ($old_ip != $current_ip) {
  Auth::logout(); // rest in peace
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this won't work, because I use laravel purely for REST API and sessions aren't being set in that case

Comment: @SenTisso Wait a second =) REST means you do not store the state... So how would you store the old IP?

Comment: @SenTisso you will need some kind of storage anyway. When we say `session` we mean `storage`, so actually session can be any kind of storage: database, in-memory DB, Redis, plain text file, other options